# Mark task as completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I’m implementing a client protocol MyProtocol over TCP/IP. The protocol’s Connect() method should have a signature similar to that of TcpClient.ConnectAsync() – that is, it should return a Task:

```
Task MyProtocol.Connect (…);
```

This method (`MyProtocol.Connect()`) should make asynchronous TCP/IP connection (via `TcpClient.ConnectAsync()`), return a non-completed task T and then periodically send a certain message M to the server – again asynchronously (via `NetworkStream.WriteAsync()`). When a certain response R is received from the server – again asynchronously (via `NetworkStream.ReadAsync()`), `MyProtocol.Connect()` should complete the task T.
I’m doing the following:

```
    // Client of the protocol:
var task = myProtocol.Connect(); // asynchronous call, we don’t want to wait until connected
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // Connected – doing an OnConnected stuff
    …
});

// MyProtocol.Connect() implementation:
public class MyProtocol
{
    private Task connectTask;
    public Task Connect(…)
    {
        var tcpIpConnectTask = mTcpIpProtocol.Connect(…);
        tcpIpConnectTask.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            connectTask = new Task();
        }
        return connectTask;
    }
}
```

Periodical sending of message M to the server obviously has to be done through a timer. Once the response R is received from the server asynchronously, `connectTask` must be marked as completed, and I don’t see ways of doing that.
Well, strictly speaking, I have managed to mark `connectTask` as completed; I’m wrapping it in `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` and use `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true)`.
However I’m wondering if this is the only, let alone the best way of accomplishing what I need? I especially don’t like the fact that `TaskCompletionSource<>` has to have a non-void task result type (I used bool), i.e. there’s no non-generic version.

Until TPL arrived, we had our own similar framework and a method `Task.NotifyCompleted()`, so we could create a Task in one place, and mark it as completed in another place – all this was working asynchronously. But all I’ve read about tasks in TPL seems to imply that a Task only completes if its delegate runs to the last line…
Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Why don't you just return `tcpIpConnectTask`? That one is complete once the connection is complete. Also if you are using .net 4.5 you can use `async/await` which simplifies the usage

Comment: `tcpIpConnectTask` is essentially what `TcpClient.ConnectAsync()` returns. As per above, MyProtocol adds its own functionality to TCP/IP, so it can only use `tcpIpConnectTask` as an intermediate result, it can't return it to the client, because the connection won't be complete when `tcpIpConnectTask` is complete, as far as MyProtocol is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using .Net 4.5, you should use C# 5.0 `async`-`await`, which is meant exactly for this kind of situations. The code could look something like (somewhat pseudo-codish):

```
public Task ConnectAsync()
{
    await ClientConnectAsync();

    while (true)
    {
        await SendMessageAsync();

        var response = await ReceiveMessageAsync();

        if (response == R)
            return;

        await Task.Delay(period);
    }
}
```

---

To actually answer your questions:

> However I’m wondering if this is the only, let alone the best way of accomplishing what I need?

If you don't want to use `async`-`await`, then yes, `TaskCompletionSource` is the only general-purpose way of doing this.

> I especially don’t like the fact that `TaskCompletionSource<>` has to have a non-void task result type (I used bool), i.e. there’s no non-generic version.

That is somewhat annoying, but it doesn't really matter, since `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`.

> But all I’ve read about tasks in TPL seems to imply that a Task only completes if its delegate runs to the last line […]

That's true for `Task`s that do have a delegate to run (those can be created using `Task.Run()`, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` or `new Task()`). But it doesn't apply to `Task`s with no delegate, those can be created using `async`-`await` or `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Very elegant solution. It somehow did not occur to me that I can use `Task.Delay()` instead of timer.
I'm not sure though whether `await Task.Delay()` would act like `Thread.Sleep()` - this I cannot afford. I mean, in my code there are other pieces that must get executed on this thread asynchronously while it's waiting at `Task.Delay()`.

Comment: @alexk `await Task.Delay()` doesn't block any threads while it's waiting. That's the whole point of `await`, to avoid blocking threads.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but it might be possible to achieve what you want with several task continuations, and once you receive the desired response set the `connectedTask` to the task received from the last `ReadAsync`.

```
public class MyProtocol
{
    private Task connectTask;
    public Task Connect()
    {
        var tcpIpConnectTask = mTcpIpProtocol.Connect();
        tcpIpConnectTask.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            bool finished = false;
            Task readAsyncTask = null;

            while(!finsihed)
            {              
                NetworkStream.WriteASync().
                ContinueWith(t1 =>
                {
                     if(t1.Exception == null)
                     {                  
                        readAsyncTask = NetworkStream.ReadASync().
                        ContinueWiht(t2 => 
                        {
                            if(t2.Exception == null)
                            {
                                if(t2.Result == /*Desired Response*/)
                                { 
                                    finished = true;
                                    connectedTask = t2;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                                // Handle ReadAsync error
                            }
                        }, null, TaskScheduler.Default);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // handle WriteAsync error
                    }
                }, null, TaskScheduler.Default);    

                // Wait for the read operation to complete. This can cause a deadlock
                // when called from a UI thread as Wait() is a blocking call. Ensure we are waiting
                // on a background thread by specifying TaskScheduler.Default
                readAsyncTask.Wait();
            }
        }, null, TaskScheduler.Default);

        return connectTask;
}
```

Alternatively if you wanted the task to have a particular result you can return `Task.FromResult(..)` which is also a completed task.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about similar option too, although have not put it into code and I'm not sure it will work nicely with timer firing up periodically, as I need. So far `TaskCompletionSource.GetResult()` looks like the way to go. And I cannot return `Task.FromResult`, because at the moment of return the task is not yet complete.